# How to write spring AOP for jax-rs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am beginner in spring AOP. My requirement is to log before invokeTestServer  method  execution.Please find my code below:

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.service" />

    <bean id="loggingAspect" class="mypackage.spring.InputAcceptorAspect" />

</beans>
```

As am trying to integrate AOP with jax-rs i dont have any specific bean to be initialized

please find below my component

```
package mypackage.service;

@Component
public class FirstProcess {

    public Response invokeTestServer() throws TestServerException{
            //Logic
        return response;
    }
}
```

My Aspect is as below
package mypackage.spring;

@Aspect

```
public class InputAcceptorAspect {

    @Before("execution(*mypackage.service.invokeTestServer(..))")
    public void logBeforeInvokingTestServer(JoinPoint joinpoint){
        logger.error("TestServer got invoked");
        System.out.println("TestServer got invoked");
    }
}
```

And am trying to test with below main class

```
package mypackage.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import mypackage.service.FirstProcess;

    public class TestAOP {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
            FirstProcess manager = context.getBean(FirstProcess.class);
            manager.invokeTestServer();
        }
    }
```

While executing the above am getting an exception failed to create bean FirstProcess defined in file..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class FirstProcess.java you are trying to create bean with annotations but annotation config is not present inside configuration. Add this tag inside application-context.xml file for bean creation using annotation config

Comment: can u provide the tag please

Comment: Added tag is not showing inside above answer, this is the required tag <context:annotation-config/>